# Como apagar valor array pelo valor de um dos elementos?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
array(3) { 
   [1]=> array(3) { 
      ["ordem"]=> string(1) "2" 
      ["img"]=> string(66) "banner.jpg" 
      ["chave"]=> string(20) "imagem_5adbea7baefaf" 
    } 
   [2]=> array(3) { 
      ["ordem"]=> int(1) "2" 
      ["img"]=> string(70) "Untitled-6.jpg" 
      ["chave"]=> string(20) "imagem_5adbeb0d0f382" 
   }
}
```

Preciso remover, apagar do array uma posição dependendo do valor "chave passado".
Por exemplo se o valor passado na função for "imagem_5adbeb0d0f382" então tenho que apagar o índice 2 do array. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: A comunidade recomenda que você responda sua própria pergunta e aceite como solução, caso tenha conseguido resolver a questão por conta própria. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$foo = [
    1 => ["ordem" => 2, "img" => "banner.jpg", "chave" => "imagem_5adbea7baefaf"],
    2 => ["ordem" => 2, "img" => "Untitled-6.jpg", "chave" => "imagem_5adbeb0d0f382"]
    ];
echo "INICIALIZAÇÃO:";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($foo);
echo "</pre>";
foreach($foo as $chave => $valor) {
    if($valor['chave'] == 'imagem_5adbeb0d0f382') {
        $chave_encontrada = $chave;
        break;
    }
}
if (isset($chave_encontrada)) {
    echo "------------<br>";
    echo "Deletando a chave ".$chave_encontrada.".<br>";
    echo "------------<br>";
    unset($foo[$chave_encontrada]);
}
echo "FINALIZAÇÃO:";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($foo);
echo "</pre>";
echo "------------<br>";
```

Só para usar de exemplo! Agora é só criar sua própria função pra fazer esse serviço aí.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui usando o seguinte:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
 if ($val['chave'] === 'imagem_5adbeb0d0f382' ) {                       
       unset($array[$key]);
   }
 }
```

Obrigado a todos!!!